# Drupal 8 - Twig - Field image - Get Inserted Image or Image by Default

Tags: image, field, drupal-8

I have entities with image fields, and some of those fields have a "default" image.

In Twig, I get the URL of my image like this:

```
{{ file_url (content.field_home_header_image['#items'].entity.uri.value) }}
```

But how can I get the default image using Twig and no need to pre-process in the PHP theme?

Comment: Did you find a solution ?